# Is there any way to use connection pool in Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am working on a project which need to use jsoup to parse html source. I found it create a new connection every time.

```
public static Connection connect(String url) {  
   Connection con = new HttpConnection();
   con.url(url);
   return con;  
}
```

Is there anyway to use a shared connection just like JDBC connection pool?

Comment: why you want to do that way?

Comment: Hi ,there is a business requirement. I need to search some information from china customs website. So i used jsoup to do this.

Comment: But jsoup nothing to do with JDBC connection. Get Html  output then use jsoup.

Answer (score -1):

In `JDBC`, all the connections are made to the same database instance so it's logical to group those together and create connection pool (as processes can re-use the connections).

However, in the above example, we are making a connection per url and hence, each connection will be separate and won't be reusable. So, in this case, it makes sense to create a new connection.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response. Maybe I can use httpclient to get html content then use jsoup to parse.

Comment: Yes, you can use `HttpClient` to get the html content.

Comment: This does not answer the question. If the remote host is the same, how JSoup can be used efficiently?